# Minimizing cheating of students

Tags: recursion, graph, combinations

Given a matrix of size m * n, place k students in such a way so that cheating in an exam could be minimized

What I thought :

With a brute force approach , create all possible combination of students placements and return the one with the minimum cheating score, while  the cheating score is defined as the sum of the Manhattan distances between each two students.

The time & space complexity of this approach is very bad, any better solution ?

Answer (score 0):

1)  Geometric intuition -- Perhaps try placing the first 4 at outer corners of the square,  then spiral inwards from there?

This would approx work for a "Pythagorean distance", maybe you can adapt a "Manhattan distance" equivalent of an inward spiralling path & then place students linearly along that.

---

2)  Or, you could place students sequentially at the next cheating-minima;  then, once all students are placed, perturb the locations to achieve an "overall minima".

I probably like 2) best as an approach.

Comment: I guess the second one is the same as brute-force approach , isn't it ? the time complexity is the same

Comment: Nope, second has a candidate solution once all students are placed and allows local search to refine. Much much more efficient, time complexity not the same in the slightest, though it achieves a "local" (probably within 1-2%) rather than a "global optimum". Probably only a few thousand iterations are needed for good local-search results -- you tell me how many iterations are needed for the global problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
int 2d array to store  4 values for every variable 
0:no neighbor
1:diagnol neighbor
2:horizontol or vertical neighbor
4:filled seat
now everytime create randomindex for row and column and first priority given to no neighbor until this expires
Then priority given to diagnol until expires
at last horizontol or vertical neighbor

repeat above steps till count=k
```